# What resistors does my circuit need?

Tags: amplifier, resistors, motor, dc, dpdt

I'm attempting to create a very basic pully system.

I am using a DC plug (12V - 2A - 24W), into a DPDT 3 position rotary switch (240V - 20A) running 2 motors from either on position (12V 25GA-370). From what I interpret the values are MAX input, can I run the current straight through or do I need to consider resistors? Therefor, I am looking for advice on resistors; where do they need to go in this circuit, what type should they be? That is if this circuit can even exist with or without these components. Any guidance helpful!
[image: I've also drawn it up in series, I understand that a DPDT is not necessary but the cosmetics of the DPDT are essential to the project and i cant find the same look with a more suitable connection]

Comment: Start with drawing and showing us the circuit.

Comment: You're powering 12V motors with a 12V power source, why do you think you need some resistors?

Comment: BTW: 240V AC for the *switch* is maximum (it might catch fire if you use more than 240V). 12V on the power supply is not a maximum, that's what it actually outputs (no matter what). 12V on the motors is a nominal rating - this is the voltage you need to get the nominal speed. The motors would also work at 6V, but they'd turn more slowly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any resistors.

If you have [a 25GA-370](https://5nrorwxhiiqoiij.leadongcdn.com/LS-25GA370-aidlpBqmKinSRrpjilkloi.pdf) rated for 12 volts and a power supply rated for 12 volts, then all you have to do is connect them.

The motor will draw what current it needs from the power supply - the power supply is capable of delivering more than the current the motor is rated for, but the motor will only take what it needs.